# Rx DebounceTime does not work

Tags: javascript, rxjs

Following the documentation of rxjs and different guide pages, does not solve my problem that `debounceTime` does not work.

```
function getValue() {
  return new rxjs.Observable(sub => {
    let counter = 0;
    setInterval(() => {
      counter++;
      sub.next(counter);
    }, 100);
  });
}


// Removing debounceTime works or set it to a value < 100.
getValue().pipe(rxjs.operators.debounceTime(1000)).subscribe(data => {
  console.log(data);
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/5bp1cwho/7/

I expected that the value comes every seconds instead of 100 ms.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**debounceTime**

> signature: debounceTime(dueTime: number, scheduler: Scheduler):
>   Observable
>
> Discard emitted values that take less than the specified time between
>   output

All your emitted items are spaced by less than 1000ms, so they are discarded.

*Note : by default, the first item is not emitted directly.*

If you want to get only the last operation `auditTime` is the operator you are searching for.

**auditTime**

> Ignores source values for `duration` milliseconds, then emits the
>   most recent  value from the source Observable, then repeats this
>   process.

```
function getValue() {
  return rxjs.interval(100);
}


// keep the last element after 1000ms 
getValue().pipe(rxjs.operators.auditTime(1000)).subscribe(data => {
  console.log(data);
});
```

If you want to do a specific processing of all the elements received within the 1000ms, you can use bufferTime.

**bufferTime**

> signature: bufferTime(bufferTimeSpan: number,
>   bufferCreationInterval: number, scheduler: Scheduler): Observable
>   Collect emitted values until provided time has passed, emit as array.

```
function getValue() {
  return rxjs.interval(100);
}

getValue().pipe(
  rxjs.operators.bufferTime(1000), 
  rxjs.operators.map(itemsList => Math.max(itemsList))
)
.subscribe(data => {
  console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I want the last value every 1000 ms. Not all values within 1000 ms. Not bufferTime. e.g. `1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6` (each all 100ms) to `10, 20, 30` (each all 1 sec).

Comment: "Yes" thanks. It there no official way with a single operator? In my opinion debounce should "debounce". Discard multiple signals within the time, but emitting the last value.

Comment: `debounceTime` is not working correctly. It should emit the last value after the set time.

Comment: ok `auditTime` works more like expected (for me) `debounceTime` :D thanks.

Comment: Late comment, but I'm again confronted with rxj's time operations and I found another solution `throttleTime`. It's like `auditTime` but emits the first value.

Comment: In addition `sampleTime` is also great for such cases. Maybe the first solution. Don't forget to initialize your subject with a value. Some operators requires it to trigger on first receive. In my case `sampleTime` is very helpful to "debounce" (control refresh) incoming data. I hope I could help.